# jQuery conditional statement based on text within element?

Tags: jquery

I would like to take the text from this element ("Drink"):

```
<div class="breadcrumb>
 <ul>
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li><a>Drink</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And use it to add a class to the site's html element.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: What's special about that element? It's the only `<a>` in that list, or it's the second one in that list, or the last one in the list, or something else?

Comment: Please consider rewording your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that is the only anchor tag in list item in the whole html,

Then  this way,  `$('li a').html()`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to add the text of last `a` of the `.breadcrumb` element as a class to the `html` element, you can use `addClass` for adding the class, and `.last()` method for selecting the last `a` descendant of the breadcrumb.

```
$('html').addClass(function() {
   return $('.breadcrumb a').last().text().toLowerCase();
});
```